# How to return errors from my PHP API - Phalcon

Tags: php, angularjs, phalcon

I'm creating an API consumer service using AngularJS and my API was coded using the Phalcon micro framework.

The problem is that in the requests I do, when the API returns an error the Angular script just stop working and I think is because I'm sending the errors in the incorrect way.

eg, If I ask for a client and if such client is not found the API returns the error in this way:

```
{"status":"error","errors":["The client was not found"],"response_time":1400898477}
```

And I set the response with this:

```
$response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found");
$response->setContent(json_encode($res));       
$response->setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
$response->send();
```

Am I sending the errors correctly or do I need to change something in my Angular requester?, because it seems that if the error is a 404 then it just stops and don't continue with the normal code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `404` should be used only when a HTTP resource is not found, in this case your API. Setting an HTTP error on it will make the request fail no matter the content, it will think that's just a error message and stop the operation. API **ordinary errors** should be sent by the API, period. Remove this `404` and you'll be fine.